# Extract first word in a string

Tags: macros, strings

The title pretty much says it all, I need a command to get the first word in a string.

Based on [this answer to another question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306381/102699), I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\FirstWord[1]{\@firstword#1 \@nil}%
\newcommand\@firstword{}%
\def\@firstword#1 #2\@nil{#1\unskip}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \FirstWord{John, Paul, George and Ringo}
\end{document}
```

It almost works, except for the fact it includes the comma. I get:

> John,

While I want just:

> John

So how can I do that?

PS: Ideally, if more than one word is inside braces, they should count as one. So `\FirstWord{{John, Paul}, George and Ringo}` should print "John, Paul".

Comment: Please clarify what constitutes a (single)  "word" for your purposes.  In particular, does "Jean-Pierre" constitute a single word or is it composed of two words (connected by a hyphen)? Separately, does the search string always commence with a word, or could it start off with punctuation and other non-alphabetic characters?

Comment: @Mico I'm working on a biblatex style and, when there's no author, entries should be cited using the first word in the title. If a book's title starts with a symbol, I guess ideally the command should ignore it. So what I need is something like... the first meaningful unit in the title that can stand on its own. But egreg's answer covers most cases, and for the exceptions the user can resort to fields like `shorthand` and `shortauthor`. Besides, I can't force possible users to use lualatex. So I'm going with his code, even though the lua option is really cool. :)

Comment: I've gone ahead and posted a second LuaLaTeX-based solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're almost there, just remove the trailing comma

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\FirstWord[1]{\@firstword#1 \@nil}%
\newcommand\@firstword{}%
\newcommand\@removecomma{}%
\def\@firstword#1 #2\@nil{\@removecomma#1,\@nil}%
\def\@removecomma#1,#2\@nil{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X\FirstWord{John, Paul, George and Ringo}X

X\FirstWord{John}X

X\FirstWord{John and Paul}X

X\FirstWord{{John, Paul}, George and Ringo}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add further tests for removing other delimiters

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\FirstWord[1]{\@firstword#1 \@nil}%
\def\@firstword#1 #2\@nil{\@removecomma#1,\@nil}%
\def\@removecomma#1,#2\@nil{\@removeperiod#1.\@nil}
\def\@removeperiod#1.#2\@nil{\@removesemicolon#1;\@nil}
\def\@removesemicolon#1;#2\@nil{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X\FirstWord{John; Paul; George; Ringo}X

X\FirstWord{John. Paul. George. Ringo}X

X\FirstWord{John}X

X\FirstWord{John and Paul}X

X\FirstWord{{John. Paul}. George. Ringo}X

\end{document}
```

---

If you don't need expandability, you can use `l3regex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\FirstWord}{m}
 {
  % split the argument at spaces
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  % get the first item
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } }
  % remove a trailing period, semicolon or comma (\Z matches the end)
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { [.;,]\Z } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  % output the result
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

X\FirstWord{John, Paul, George and Ringo}X

X\FirstWord{John; Paul; George; Ringo}X

X\FirstWord{John. Paul. George. Ringo}X

X\FirstWord{John}X

X\FirstWord{John and Paul}X

X\FirstWord{{John, Paul}, George and Ringo}X

X\FirstWord{{John. Paul}. George. Ringo}X

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Just one thing… what if there's a period or a colon or a semicolon? I tried defining `\@removeperiod`,  `\@removecolon` and so on, and adding one after the other in `\def\@firstword`, but I get "paragraph ended before \@removeperiod was complete".

Comment: @danielbmarques You can add further tests for removing the undesired trailing character.

Answer (score 3):

Admittedly a bit late to the game, but here's a second LuaLaTeX-based solution, which generalizes the [earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316754/5001) by @Nasser. This answer's pattern search algorithm satisfies the following criteria:

- If the string to be searched *starts* with a substring that's delimited by matching curly braces, the entire substring is returned.
- Otherwise, the first *word* is returned. Here, a "word" is taken to be either a collection of alphabetic characters -- e.g., "John" or "Nicolò" -- or a *hyphenated pair* of words -- e.g., "Kröller-Müller" and "Rhys-Davies". (Put differently, a hyphenated word is taken to be two single words that are joined by exactly one instance of `-`; the only restriction on the first word in the hyphenated pair is that it contain at least two characters.) Any non-alphabetic characters that precede the "word" in the full string are automatically discarded. The Lua code is unicode-aware, i.e., the words may contain non-ASCII alphabetic characters (such as `ö`, `ü`, and `ò`).

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment and '\luastring' macro
%% Lua-side code: A Lua function that does most of the work
\begin{luacode}
function fw ( s )
   if string.find ( s , '^%b{}' ) then
      first = string.sub ( string.match ( s , '%b{}' ), 2, -2 )
   else
      first = unicode.utf8.match ( s , '%w+%-?%w+' )
   end
   tex.sprint ( first ) 
end
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code: A macro that invokes the Lua function
\newcommand{\FW}[1]{\directlua{fw(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}

\def\lst{{John and Paul} but not George or Ringo}
\FW{\lst}

\def\lst{'{Bay- Day} Hay}
\FW{\lst}

\def\lst{Kröller-Müller and Schwassmann-Wassmann}
\FW{\lst}

\end{document}
```