# Changing AwesomeCV section highlighting to highlight whole first word

Tags: macros, formatting, color, templates, section-titles

Basically same question as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509756/change-the-color-of-titles-to-include-whole-word-in-awesome-cv/509808#509808?newreg=5f9915274d0f453d9ba51317c7fb2150), which has not been answered.

Base AwesomeCV highlights the first three characters of the section title string using the below code in the macro.

```
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  \ifbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{{\color{awesome}#1#2#3}}{#1#2#3}%
}
```

I would like it to highlight the first *word*, whatever the input is. So far I've been unable to get it to work, any help is appreciated!

Comment: To color the entire word "About" in Awesome CV rather than just the first three letters I used this in coverletter.tex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509756/change-the-color-of-titles-to-include-whole-word-in-awesome-cv/601679#601679

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put a space after the macro parameter.

```
%\makeatletter
\def\@sectioncolor#1 {%
    \ifbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}
        {\textcolor{awesome}{#1}\ }
        {#1\ }
}
\@sectioncolor Hello world!
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround. Please note that I am not efficient in LaTeX, especially not in making macros. That said, here's a solution for anyone looking into this in the future:

I replaced the original definition of `\@sectioncolor` (as above) with the following block, which is adapted from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306340/make-just-part-of-titles-uppercase-with-biblatex/306381#306381):

```
% Awesome section color
\newcommand\SectionStyle[1]{\@sectionstyle#1 \@nil}
\newcommand\@sectionstyle{}
\def\@sectionstyle#1 #2\@nil{\textcolor{awesome}{#1} #2\unskip}
```

Then, I also had to replace the `\lettersectionstyle` command (and for the resume, `\sectionstyle`) with the following:

```
\newcommand*{\lettersectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{14pt}
{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{text}\SectionStyle{#1}}}
```

And now the macro works, even with the different awesome colors!